# Thermal expansion during the course of melting (in metals specifically)

Tags: materials, metals, thermal-expansion

The question is with regards to Thermal Expansion at the point of melting.

My basic understanding is that a material will generally undergo linear thermal expansion until some phase change occurs (crystal formation, melt, etc) that changes the material behavior. Take Aluminum, for example. It has a linear expansion coefficient of ~23E-6 /K when solid, but might go as high as ~98E-6 /K [when melted](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00319109508030263). What I can't find, however, is how much expansion occurs over the process of the melting transition itself? It seems like if a solid metal with a poisson ratio of 0.35 (compressible material) transitions to a liquid with poisson's ratio of ~0.5 (incompressible), there must be some large amount of expansion as it fully "decompresses" to that point. Kind of how water which we all learned in elementary school counter-intuitively expands when frozen, I would assume metal behaves more intuitively with a large expansion when melted.

Is there any formula to predict this expansion amount during melt, assuming all heat is contributing to phase transition and not increasing temperature?

Comment: A quick reading on the articles on the web, my impression is not all metals are created equal, while almost all metals expand under heat, there are exceptions. Also, metals with a higher melting point tend to have lower thermal expansion. Interesting topic, but I doubt there is a precise answer to it.

Comment: Pattern makers shrinkage factors are easy enough to find for any engineering metal . Just reverse it for expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Phase transitions are isothermal processes, so I think your best bet would be to calculate a weighted average of the molar volumes of the two phases. These values can be easily looked up.

Comment: Correct: phase transitions are isothermal as I said ("all heat is contributing to phase transition and not increasing temperature"). Do you know a resource that supplies the molar volumes of metals immediately before melting onset and immediately after? Common ones like aluminum and copper I can locate, but for unusual alloys I was hoping there was some predictive formula.

Comment: @TrevorBuckner if you know the P-T phase diagram of the system, you can use the Clausius-Clapeyron equation to calculate the specific volume change of the phase transition. For exotic alloys these may not be available, but the volume change on melting is a relatively easy experimental measurement. For a solid-state transformation, you could measure the lattice parameter via XRD, perhaps. A back-of-the-envelope calculation could use the packing of hard spheres. For example, close-packed spheres (FCC, HCP) fill 74% of available space, while random packing (liquid) is closer to 62%.